# Develop a simple Java EJB 2.0 project with websphere 8.5 and Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, ibm-rad, ejb-2.x

I want to create a simple project with Java EJB 2.0 and websphere 8.5 (without maven) in Eclipse Luna.

I can not find any good tutorial as EJB 2.0 is quite old. will you guys guide me with good tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

[EJB 2.0 Development with WebSphere Studio Application Developer](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246819.pdf) and [Implementing EJB 2.x applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_implement_ejb2x_apps.html) from IBM look like decent resources.

Comment: Actually I am using Eclipse Luna, I can not find any option to create j2ee 1.3 Enterprise Application Project. Which eclipse version should I use?

Comment: Check out Eclipse Luna documentation at https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ejb.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fceresrc.html

Comment: Are there any solid reasons to use EJB 2.0 for new project in 2018? The spec is 18+ years old already.

Comment: Actually there is an existing project on EJB 2.0 which has been developed on IBM RAD, we have to migrate it in Eclipse (Client's demand). I am new to EJB so was eager to learn a simple EJB app development.

Comment: the link you mentioned in the comment literally had directions to create a new project :P. like just go on new and create ejb project :P. Will you please help me with a simple CRUD application demo